# How does ActiveRecord link records together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So this has been surprisingly difficult to locate a quick answer to. I'm using ActiveRecord in a pure console app, and I have my classes set up like so:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :lines
belongs_to :owner
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :profiles
end
```

Now normally i'd do something like..

```
Profile.create( :thing => "thing", :otherthing => "otherthing" )
```

How does AR know to link this instance of profile to an owner? What about a specific owner already in the database? How do I tell it? How would I do all of the links at once? (line, to profile, to owner)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this to understand the basics. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: That's sort of unhelpful. Let's say I'm creating a line, a profile, and an owner all at once. Judging by the guide, I'd do something like Line.Profiles.Owners.create? What if these tables have columns that are named identically?

Comment: Which part of the guide says this? I would suggest that you really start from the fundamentals to get a feel of Rails' ActiveRecord. But I'll try to answer your question. If you want to create different models all at once, then simply do `Line.create!(params[:line])` and `Owners.create!`. But if you're looking into associating different models, an eg: `@profile = @owner.profiles.create!(params[:profile])`

Comment: The relevant portion is near the top where they explain setting up the relations in your database classes..

With this change, creating a new order for a particular customer is easier (etc)

Comment: Sure, but notice the capitalization. Since a `Customer` has many `Order`s, so an instance of customer, `@customer`, due to the declared `has_many :orders` in the `Customer` model, makes it possible to create an `Order` and associate it with `@customer` at the same time using the syntax you mentioned above.

Comment: Can those be linked back three at a time instead of two? An owner has many profiles, and a profile has many lines.

Something like..

`@owner = Owner.create(:name => "Tom Fubar")`
`@profile = @owner.profiles.create(:title => "Test")`
`@line = @profile.lines.create(:line1 => "Stuff goes here"`

Comment: Yeah, I think that's possible. Alternatively, you can create the model which doesn't rely on any associations first. In you case, make a Line first. Then find the Profile you want to link the newly created Line to.

Comment: Thanks :) You worded this in a way that finally got through to me.